# YouTube JavaScript Player API seekTo() unreliable

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I'm doing this:

```
onPlayerReady: function(player) {
    ...
    player.seekTo(time, true)
    player.playVideo()
    ...
}
```

but sometimes the video starts from the start although `time` is a few minutes in... This happens roughly 1/4 of the time and it's disturbing because my service depends on this working all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: is `onPlayerReady` supposed to be `onYouTubePlayerReady` [reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#EventHandlers)

Comment: I know... this is a `React.js` component ... but the event comes from `onYouTubePlayerReady`.. I'm now trying to seek after the video has already started playing as described here: http://www.scottdstrader.com/blog/ether_archives/001683.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call seekTo() after the playing event (1) has been received. So, the sequence is:

```
onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId)
onPlayerStateChange(newState == 1)
player.seekTo(offset, true)
```

http://www.scottdstrader.com/blog/ether_archives/001683.html